# How to find the basis of polynomials functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let S be the subspace of ℝ4 consisting of the solutions to the following system of equations:

$x_1−x_2−2x_3−3x_4  =  0$

$−3x_1+5x_2+10x_3+5x_4  =  0$

$−3x_1+4x_2+8x_3+8x_4  =  0$

Give a basis for S.

I row reduced:

\begin{bmatrix}   1&-3&-3\\-1&5&4\\-2&10&8\\-3&5&8    \end{bmatrix}

to

\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0  \end{bmatrix}

I thought that basis is:

\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\\-2\\-3 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -3\\5\\10\\5 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -3\\4\\8\\8 \end{bmatrix}

However, the answer is wrong and one of the correct answer is

Number of Vector: 1

\begin{bmatrix} 0\\-2\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}

How is number of vector is 1 and not 3? and how did they get the basis?

Answer (score 1):

If you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1−x_2−2x_3−3x_4= 0\\−3x_1+5x_2+10x_3+5x_4=0\\−3x_1+4x_2+8x_3+8x_4=0,\end{array}\right.$$what you get is $x_1=x_4=0$ and $x_2=-2x_3$. So, yes, your space is $1$-dimensional and the answer that you were given is correct.

The space of the solutions could be $3$-dimensional only if two of the equations were multiples of the third one.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your own work, you’ll find that the answer is incorrect. None of those basis vectors satisfy the system of equations. You had more or less the right idea, but the wrong matrix. You computed a basis for its column space, but what you need is the null space of its transpose.

In matrix form, the system of equations is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-2&-3\\-3&5&10&5\\-3&4&8&8\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix} = 0,$$ i.e., you need to write the coefficients of each equation as a *row* of the matrix. Reducing this matrix yields $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&2&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ from which you can read that its null space is spanned by $(0,-2,1,0)^T$.